# Out of memory when booting ubuntu or any linux distro from LIVE USB

Tags: ram

Scenario:

- I had ubuntu 13.10 installed.
- tried to boot with a windows usb
- windows setup frozen after selecting "Delete" on an empty ntfs partition
- restarted the laptop with power button

Now when i try to boot, it enters grub_rescue console.

So, i made a live usb with ubuntu.
I get this kind of errors when booting from live usb.
[image]

I tried different linux distros (manjaro, xubuntu) on different usb drives, same issue, stuck on killing processes.

Also when I try to boot with a windows usb, it hangs at windows logo.

... edit

After a while waiting to boot, it stucks on this kind of erros:
[image]

Comment: how did you create bootable live usb?

Comment: "dd" command line utility from mac / unetbootin / universal usb installer from windows, same result.

Comment: on boot from usb did you choose try ubuntu or install ubuntu option?

Comment: Tried both, same. Also tried with many boot options (nomodeset, etc) same result.

Comment: Same happens to me for fedora 20. Any idea, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late, but I had the same problem with my Dell L502X; let my explain my situation and maybe it could be useful to you:

I removed my Optical CD bay to add an SSD disk and after a year of it working well on both Linux and Windows, I decided to perform a new Windows installation which resulted in corruption. After this I could not boot into either Linux or Windows nor a Linux LiveUSB (getting the same message as you) or even try to make a new installation. Everything I tried failed.

To solve the problem I removed the SSD from the Optical bay: it was completely broken and flashed the BIOS (It was corrupted as well).

Only after all that, I was able reinstall my OSes and no "Out of memory" messages are displayed any more when booting from a LiveUSB.

Hope it can be useful for someone in the same situation.